# Invite github user to gitlab project

Tags: github, gitlab

I want to invite a github account to become a member of my gitlab project. When I look for his nick in the **Invite member** window I can't find him...
[image]

is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Github and Gitlab are two totally different services. So what you are trying to do is not possible. You can invite only an existing gitlab user by user name. You will have to invite by email if the person is not an existing Gitlab user. Then once the invite is received, the user can use Github account to login(social login)